# Need Jquery or Javascript code for a drop down menu to display selected divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im very new to JS/ JQuery, so even the basic stuff Im listing could be flawed, let alone what Im trying to do.

This is what I want to happen:

//drop down menu (are my method/action correct?)

```
<form method="get" action="javascript:void(0)">
        <select name="menus">
            <option value="div1">Menu 1</option>
            <option value="div2">Menu 2</option>
            <option value="div3">Menu 3</option>
        </select>
</form>
```

//Info to be displayed and hidden.

```
<div id="div1"> Stuff </div>
<div id="div2"> More Stuff </div>
<div id="div3"> Even More Stuff </div>
```

But I need the coding to make it work. I was trying to do some things myself, but this is all I got, and it obviously isn't working, nor is it finished.

```
function changediv(){
    // determine the index of the selected item in the ddl
    var id = document.getElementById("menus").selectedIndex;
    // determine the value of the selected item in the ddl
    var menu = document.getElementById("menus").options[id].value;
    // set background color of content
    document.getElementById("") = menu;
}
```

I want to note, when the page loads, I want Div1 to show automatically. Then from the menu, can go to div2, or div3, and back and forth from the menu between all three.

So idk, if that would be an if statement of sorts. Like if Div1 is selected, div2 and div3 get a display: none property of some sort?

Thanks!

Comment: What is do you need help with i do not understand question?

Comment: Idk how else to explain it. I thought it was quite clear. Maybe if you can explain where you got lost I can help flesh out the problem?

Comment: You want to toggle the visibility of div1 to div3 depending on what's selected in the dropdown?

Comment: Yes sir. When you load the page first time, it loads Div1, and there is a drop down menu. When you select option 1 through 3, it will show div's 1, 2, or 3. For example - load page, Div1 shows. go to menu, select option 3, Div 1 disappears, Div 3 is now showing. Go to menu again, select option 2, Div 3 disappears, Div 2 is now showing.

I want to put some tables for stats per season in the divs. And each option will be a different hockey season. Each div would be each season and the stats for the season.

For a visual representation this is the exact page:
http://www.phlbombers.com/stats.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an easy task with `jQuery`, here you have:

**HTML**

```
<select id="menus">
  <option value="div1">Menu 1</option>
  <option value="div2">Menu 2</option>
  <option value="div3">Menu 3</option>
</select>

<div id="div1"> Stuff </div>
<div id="div2"> More Stuff </div>
<div id="div3"> Even More Stuff </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
//---Show DIV function
function showDiv(selector){

    //---Select div to show
    var element = $("div#" + selector);

    //---Hide all div except the above div
    $("div[id^='div']").not(element).hide();

    //---Show the div
    element.show();

}

//---When the select changes
$("#menus").on("change", function(){

    showDiv( $(this).val() );

});

//---Show the first div by default
showDiv("div1");
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/8spzskhv/)

Comment: This did it, perfectly. Thank you very much!